# Creating a dropdown in Angular-Schema-Form not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I'm having some difficulty rendering a dropdown in ASF. If I add an enum to the Schema it renders the dropdown with values one/two, not the "name" from the titleMap. This also doesn't allow to have a list of options served from the server. Please help me find what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

I have the following code in my Controller:

```
    $scope.row = { choice: "one" };

    $scope.form = [
        {
            key: "choice",
            type: "select",
            titleMap: [
                { value: "one", name: "One" },
                { value: "two", name: "More..." }
            ]
        }
    ];

    $scope.schema = {
        type: "object",
        properties:{
            choice: {
                type: "string"
            }
        }
    };
```

And my HTML is:

```
    <form sf-schema="schema" sf-form="form" sf-model="row"></form>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work without adding an 'enum' to the schema. Went ahead and created my own custom field type to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the properties **type** of **$scope.schema**

```
$scope.schema = {
    type: "object",
    properties:{
        choice: {
            type: "object"
        }
    }
};
```